# jQuery Ui Tabs 'selecting' a tab not working when updated from jQuery UI 1.8.2 to 1.9.2

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs

A few hours ago I finally updated my jQuery UI library from 1.8.2 to 1.9.2. Before the update I had a some code that selects a tab dynamically based on the tab's id

```
jQuery("#page-content").tabs("select",1);
```

But now after the update, it stopped working! I would really appreciate if you could tell me the new way of doing this same thing. I already looked at the API on the jQueryUI site but could not find anything.

Thank you very much.

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
jQuery("#page-content").tabs( "option", "active", 1 );
```

check the below link

http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-select-method

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have solved this. I was applying a custom css class to the tabs that were selected but looks like the jQuery UI guys removed the .ui-tabs-selected class from the tabs that are selected.